springframework.web.servlet.resource.NoResourceFoundException: No static resource
I'm sending the following request:
POST http://localhost:8080/bookings/newBooking
Content-Type: application/json
{
  "bookingId": 1,
  "user": {
    "userId": 3,
    "username": "user1",
    "password": "password1",
    "email": "name@mail.com"
  },
  "paymentId": 4
}

And I get the following error

"org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.NoResourceFoundException: No
static resource bookings/newBooking.
org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler.handleRequest(ResourceHttpRequestHandler.java:585).org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.handle(HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.java:52)...


BookingController:
package org.soa.booking;
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/bookings")
public class BookingController {

    private final BookingService bookingService;

    @Autowired
    public BookingController(BookingService bookingService) {
        this.bookingService = bookingService;
    }

    @PostMapping("/newBooking")
    public Booking createBooking(@RequestBody Booking booking) {
        return bookingService.createBooking(booking);
    }
}

SoaApplication:
package org.soa;
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class SoaApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        SpringApplication.run(SoaApplication.class, args);
    }

build.gradle:
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.3.4'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.6'
}

group = 'org.soa'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

java {
    toolchain {
        languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(17)
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'javax.persistence:javax.persistence-api:2.2'
    implementation 'org.mariadb.jdbc:mariadb-java-client:3.0.5'
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            exclude 'org/soa/passenger/**'
            exclude 'org/soa/flight/**'
            exclude 'org/soa/payment/**'
            exclude 'org/soa/airport/**'
        }
    }
}


tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

From what I understand is that the Controller is being treated as a request for a static resource rather than being handled by the Controller. However, I don't know how to solve it, any insights highly appreciate it.

When same Spring Boot App is serving both static and dynamic content, Its best practice to prefix controller methods with api word i.e., "/api/bookings/newBooking". If you don't follow this then you need to update WebConfigurer with complex expressions to handle which ones are static vs dynamic.

Why is there an @RestController on your SoaApplication? That is weird. That being said judging from what you have added to the question it should just work, so without knowing your additional configuration this will be impossible to answer. You can enable DEBUG logging for org.springframework.web or the whole of it and see what is happening upon receiving your request.

@M.Deinum Please take a look at my build.gradle file

Why are you adding javax.persistence as a depenency? This means you are using incompatible things with Spring Boot 3. spring-boot-starter-data-jpa already contains all you need including the jakarta.persistence things. Why are you excluding everything in your sourcesests? Basically excluding all sources in there, remove the sourceSets element in your build.gradle.
